# url redirect not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the html code

```
<head runat="server">
<title>Untitled Page</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function func()
    {
        document.location.href="www.google.com"
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type="button" runat="server" onclick="func();" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The redirect isn't working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `document.location`.

Use **either** `window.location.href`, or `location.href` (I prefer the latter :))

Answer (score 2):

Because it should be `window.location.href`.

**REF:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location